# sql query concerning image

Tags: mysql, sql, image

I'm trying to run this query but it doesn't stop loading although it works well when i remove the image from the query

```
SELECT Image.Image ,Pharmacy.name,Delivery.phone,Delivery.address,Request.Timestamp 
          FROM Delivery
          INNER JOIN Pharmacy ON Delivery.Pharmacy_id = Pharmacy._id
          INNER JOIN Request ON Delivery.Request_id = Request._id
          INNER JOIN Image ON Request._id = Image.Request_id
          WHERE Image.Image IS NOT NULL
          ORDER BY Delivery._id DESC;
```

Comment: How large are these tables?

Comment: one Thousand Records

Comment: Image table is only 1k row? Can you take out the WHERE image.image is NULL and see if you get a hit.

Comment: I inserted this part recently and nothing changed it seems there is a problem on joining the image table.

Comment: It's most likely this syntax: Image ON Request._id = Image.Request_id. Are you sure there's a Request._ID ? Shouldn't this be INNER JOIN Image ON Request.Request_ID = Image.Request_ID

Comment: Also, please edit the question. This has nothing to do with an actual "image" in the database. But rather there's an issue with query "hanging".

Comment: no columns name are right and working in other queries.

Comment: I would check your Request and Image table to see if you can really link Image.Request_ID = Request._id. I bet you this should be Image.Request_ID = Request.Request._id

Comment: No I said Columns name are right and tested in other queries.